# ¿Cuál es la abreviatura correcta para "Asociación de Academias de la Lengua Española"?

Tags: abreviaturas

Quisiera saber por qué la abreviatura correcta para "Asociación de Academias de la Lengua Española" es ASALE, en vez de AALE. ¡Muchas gracias!

> "La Asociación de Academias de la Lengua Española (ASALE) se conformó en México en 1951, originariamente compuesta por veintiuna academias, actualmente está integrada por las veintitrés academias de la lengua española existentes en el mundo."

Comment: Creo que es discrecional de las entidades autonombrarse y tal vez consideraron que AsALE era más pronunciable que AALE

Answer (score 5):

De [las recomendaciones para las abreviaturas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=fKODyKTfZD6s0mX7bz), apartado tercero "Formación":

> **Formación**. La abreviatura ha de ser eficaz y, por eso, debe suprimir como mínimo dos letras de la palabra abreviada (mejor, tres, si la palabra es suficientemente larga, para poder ahorrar, al menos, dos caracteres, ya que una de las letras suprimidas es reemplazada por el punto de cierre); aun así, hay ejemplos difundidos en que solo se elimina una: vid. por vide (‘véase’)

Existen dos procedimientos para formar abreviaturas:

a) Por truncamiento, suprimiendo letras o sílabas finales

b) Por contracción, eliminando letras centrales y dejando solo las más representativas: dpto. o depto. por departamento, admr. por administrador. Entre las abreviaturas formadas por contracción están las que presentan la letra o letras finales voladas: n.o por número, af.mo por afectísimo.

Entiendo que "ASALE" cumple estas normas para "**As**ociación de **A**cademias de la **L**engua **E**spañola" con la ventaja de ser ligeramente más "pronunciable" (y ser recordado mejor) que "AALE"

Entiendo por tanto que tanto "AALE" como "ASALE" son correctas desde el punto de vista técnico, pero dicha asociación promovió "ASALE" frente "AALE" porque la primera tiene una ligera ventaja (algo subjetiva, sí, pero suena mejor al oído y se recuerda mejor).

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus detalladas explicaciones!

Comment: ¿De verdad suena mejor al oido? "¡Traéle la hoguera! ¡Asále!"

Comment: @Obie2.0 "_Aale_ venga va, dale ahí" ;-) Bromas aparte, como digo en la respuesta es un poco subjetivo, pero yo creo que sí. En España sería muy difícil oír "¡Asále!" en lugar de "ásale", por lo menos. Y "AALE" te obliga a diferenciar esas dos primeras aes de alguna manera. Seguro que tú no pronuncias "RAE" como "Erre-A-E", pero "EEUU" sí, letra a letra. Así que sí que creo que haya cierta ventaja en meter esa consonante extra

Comment: Eso fue un error, quería escribir: "¡Tráele a la hoguera! ¡Ásale!" Por supuesto bromeaba también.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus detalladas explicaciones!